# Evolutionary reasoning behind redundancy of CST and RuST

Tags: evolution, neuroanatomy

According to my neuro-anatomy class, both the Corsticospinal Tract (CST) and the Rubrospinal Tract (RuST) control upper limb movement. What the evolutionary reasoning behind this redundancy and the fact that the RuST is much more important in non-human primates when compared to humans?

Comment: @Susan thanks for the suggestion, I've edited my question